# Mixing passport username and password with some kind token strategy

Tags: express, authentication, token, passport.js, passport-jwt

I have an express app which uses a username and password to auth. It's part of a MERN stack.

I'm building a *separate* application and want to use some auth token to authenticate with the server.

How do I mix between two strategies, for example, `passport-http-bearer` (or passport-jwt)  and `passport-local`? Both will use the same API endpoints. But I want to use local for the frontend and Bearer for the other separate application.

From what I understood, I will have to add `passport.authenticate('bearer')` like this

```js
app.use(passport.authenticate('bearer'))

// OR in specific routes

app.get('/', passport.authenticate('bearer'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'hello', user: req.user || 'No user' })
})
```

But this will result in `Unauthorized` in the first application. (Using a username or password)